# Python: Type Annotations, how to define elements of a tuple?

Tags: python, static-typing, type-annotation

Here is a minimal case.

```
def foo(x:int, y:int) -> tuple: 
    return (x*y, y//2)
```

It's very tempting to be able to write `-> tuple(:int, :int)` which is not a valid format. Is there a correct approach in this case, or is it still a gray area until python moves further down the type annotation road?

edit:
It's apparently possible to do something of the like

```
def bar(x, y) -> ((str, int), (str, int)): 
     return ("%s+%s" %(x,y), x+y), ("%s-%s" %(x,y), x-y)
```

Comment: See the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), which has recently seen a lot of development.  If you're really curious, you can also check out the [python-ideas list archives](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-January/thread.html), where Guido started a thread about this PEP in mid-January 2015.

Comment: Since python 3.9 [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) we can write tuple[int, int]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is now a way to annotate this case:

```
from typing import Tuple
def foo(x:int, y:int) -> Tuple[int, int]: 
    return (x*y, y//2)
```

Note: python run-time won't complain about `-> (int, int)`, but it is not correct type annotation according to PEP 484. In other words, you can use it if you want to create your a mini-language using type hints for your own purposes; but it's not accepted by the python typing standard (PEP 484).

Comment: how to annotate `[[str, int]]` ? Can i use Tuple despite the element `[str, int]` being list like `List[Tuple[str,int]]`?

Comment: @qrtLs No you cannot. Python type annotations can only represent a list where all items have the same type. There is no way to say that `my_list` is a list with two items of type `str` and `int`. 

Rationale: a variable cannot change its type, and it's far too common for a list to change its length. If length can change, and items are not of the same type, it's unclear what the type system should do when user attempts to append say an `int` to a `List[int, str]`. The chosen solution is that you cannot specify length at all, and the type of all items has to be the same.

Comment: @qrtLs But you can and maybe should just *use an actual tuple in your return value*: if the list is always two elements, and they always have the same type, why is it a list to begin with? To make it easier for the function that receives it to mutate it? Is that a strong enough reason in your case.

Comment: Since python 3.9 [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) we can write tuple[int, int]

Answer (score 5):

`typing.Tuple` is now deprecated as of Python 3.9. You should use the built-in `tuple` type instead (no import needed):

```py
def foo(x:int, y:int) -> tuple[int, int]: 
    return (x*y, y//2)
```

The [docs for `typing.Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) state:

> *Deprecated since version 3.9:* `builtins.tuple` now supports subscripting (`[]`). See [PEP 585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/) and [Generic Alias Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias).

Comment: Note: `tuple(int, int)` is incorrect format. Python will complain: `tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2`

Comment: You should use `tuple[int, int]`, _not_ `tuple(int, int)`. The code in the answer typechecks correctly -- see [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=7844a0709e2b1b2cc979faba22c2b1f9) mypy playground link.

Answer (score 3):

> **Edit (2023):** Although this answer was useful when it was posted and is still historically interesting, its advice is now somewhere between irrelevant, misleading, and harmful. Other answers already mention that [PEP-484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) formalized a different syntax since this was posted.

No, there is not a canonical way to do this as of yet. Python type annotations are a relatively new addition to the language, so they are still somewhat limited.

For now, you could maybe use a tuple literal:

```
def foo(x:int, y:int) -> (int, int):
    return (x*y, y//2)
```

That, or a string literal such as:

```
def foo(x:int, y:int) -> 'tuple(int, int)':
    return (x*y, y//2)
```

Both of these convey your intention pretty clearly.

Comment: I'm still hoping the actual input and return type will be enforced at some point, rather than just serving as a fancy comment syntax.

Comment: Eh, I'm not very eager for that.  It defeats the purpose of Python's dynamic typing and ruins a great feature of the language.  I mean, if you want static typing, why not use Java or C++ (which are both generally faster)?  Python is great because it is dynamic.  Of course, that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: I should clarify, I only meant enforced (on annotated code) - it's really weird for me that I can write `def foo() -> int:` and return a `str`; granted that probably doesn't happen often; but `def foo() -> int` returning a `float` probably does.

Comment: In light of the recent developments in PEP 484, this answer might be a little out of date. See my comment on OP's question.

Comment: @user3467349: Python, as we know it, is never going to have enforced static types. That's just not what Python is. If you follow the development of Python, you'll get a visceral sense of just how adamant Guido and the core developers are that these are *annotations*, **not** *declarations*. But if you like static typing, or even hybrid systems which have optional, cherry-picked static typing, you have other choices besides Python. The two that come most quickly to mind are Cython and Nim (formerly Nimrod), and they are by no means the only ones.

Comment: @JohnY I like the static typing in Julia quite a bit if that's what you mean (albeit I'm less satisfied by how it interacts with the Julia-style of dynamic dispatch) but yes I don't see any advantage to not enforcing static typing in code that does use it, it can just lead to simply incorrect annotations, which is actually worse than no annotations at all.

Comment: @user3467349: I think you are getting hung up on this notion that annotations somehow "statically type" the code they annotate. This could not be further from the truth. There is NO SUCH THING as statically typed Python code, PERIOD. So there isn't anything to enforce. It would be like saying "incorrect comments are worse than no comments at all". Well, yes that's true, but comments are not for enforcement, they are for... comments. So please understand that the terminology of **annotation** is very deliberate. They are **NOT** declarations.

Comment: @JohnY It sounds like you are more "hung up" then I am: on dogmatically asserting python principals. - Consider this: if there was a 100% reliable way to check `assert($comment is True)` would you use it?, when would you ever not use it? You might say comment validation enforcement (even if we had some 0% error radical AI would be an exceptional change); but unlike which static typing enforcement on annotations would be a normal change that everyone (or near everyone) would be accustomed to from other languages. I can't see a single argument for not *enforcing it*.

Comment: When I set `(str, str)` VS Code **Pylance** language server said: _Tuple expression not allowed in type annotation Use `Tuple[T1, ..., Tn]` instead_. It said OK for @max' answer: `Tuple[str, str]`.